# Do undead benefit from magic items?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, undead

Could an undead in 3.5e D&D such as a skeleton benefit from wearing magic items like rings of protection?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Undead can benefit from magic items like any other creature.

The only exceptions would be items that have conditions they don't meet or do things that don't apply..like CON bonuses.  They could technically wear items boost their immunities but it would be a waste in most circumstances (poison/disease/etc).

Turn/Rebuke resistance would obviously be a great resistance to stack!

Caveat: for command activated items they must be able to activate and skeletons would generally be unable to activate voice triggers.

Comment: Any trigger that requires choice, or conscious awareness of the item even, wouldn't work. They don't have any consciousness or free will to do that with.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, Good point!  However, not 100% accurate across the board as there are some "intelligent" undead who would be able to activate them. (Normal Skeletons & Zombies do not qualify which is what the original question used as an example)

Comment: Yeah, I meant specifically skeletons and just forgot to say. A vampire would do just fine.

Comment: We can probably just go with "Anything with an Int score higher than 2", no?

Comment: Oh - One thing worth mentioning is that even if a Skeleton or other mindless undead monster can use a magic item, it's unlikely to do so of its own accord. Someone had to put that ring of protection on the skeleton's finger - unless it died wearing it and the necromancer didn't bother searching the body when animating it.

Comment: There are spells that can restore a zombie to intelligence that it had in life, allowing it to use weapons and armor as well. Magic items of this sort can be used for mindless undead, but they would only gain any special always on abilities, such as fire resistance (great for vampires and the like), invulnerability, or spell resistance.

Comment: Pg 62 Libris mortis- Awaken Undead - Grant sentience to mindless undead minion.